# Onchange event not providing right id for the particular iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I am trying to map through an array of objects provided from a backend api and then render each objects as rows in a table. And every row as a file input to upload an image but I need to send a request to the api with the id of the particular row. So, am listening on an onChange event on the file input but the issue is that the request keeps sending the id of the first row instead of the selected row. Here's the code

```js
{
    payments.map((payment) => (
        <tr className="row" key={payment._id}>
            <td className="cell">{payment.status}</td>
            <td className="cell">{payment.amount}</td>
            <td className="cell">{payment.paymentfor}</td>
            <td className="cell">
                {new Date(payment.createdAt).toDateString()}
            </td>
            <td className="cell">
                <div className="upload">
                    <label htmlFor="upload" className="upload-button">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} /> Upload a photo
                    </label>
                    <input
                        id="upload"
                        type="file"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            uploadFile(payment._id, e);
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ));
}
```

Please help!!

Comment: looks good. Post your `uploadFile` function

Comment: You can pass first event object after payment_id.
onChange={(e) => 
                            uploadFile(e, payment._id);
                        }

Comment: Just to get the most obvious thing out of the way. Have you checked the contents of `payments` with `console.log(payments)`? Do all `payments` indeed have a unique `_id`? I would assume so, but you can never be too sure on SO.

Comment: It's not solving your problem, but you have to provide different `id` and `htmlFor` values for each `input` and `label` element.